# LinearRegression().fit() Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

```
import math
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing, svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
test_size=0.2)

clf =  LinearRegression()

clf.fit(X_train, y_train) 
# Test the accuracy
accuracy = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

I'm trying to fit split value into LinearRegression.fit() but it shows  Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Comment: The error message is quite self-explanatory in this case.. did you check for NaN or inf values in your input data?

Comment: It's fixed. The input contained NaN values